# Segment Tree Query for Maximum Number

Tags: algorithm, segment-tree

I have given a an array `A` of n integer , and `Q` query in the form of `X D` for each query i have to find the maximum element in sub array `[Ax , A(x-D),A(x-2D)..]`

For example:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,17,8]
we have query 7 2
Sub Array [17,5,3,1] Ans=17
```

How can we solve this with a time complexity better than `O(Q*N)` since no index is updated , can it be solved offline with some technique

I don't think `Square Decomposition` will work here.

Comment: Is `O(sqrt N)` per query good enough? If not, what makes you think that it won't work?

Comment: What (in this context) is a `Segment Tree`, and what is the connection to the problem presented in this question? If `Q` is a query, what is the `Q` in `O(Q*N)`?

Answer (score 1):

Let `D` greater than `sqrt(N)`. Then the sequence x, x - d, x - 2 * d, ... contains at most `sqrt(N)` elements. Thus, a naive solution works in `O(sqrt(N))` per query in this case.

Let `D <= sqrt(N)`. There are at most `sqrt(N)` such distinct `D`'s. Let's iterate over them. For a fixed value `d`, we can compute `f[i] = max(a[i], f[i - d])` for all `i` in linear time (boundary conditions need to be handled properly). The the answer for all queries `(X, D)`, where `D = d`, is just `f[X]`.

The total time complexity is `O((N + Q) * sqrt(N))`. This solution uses a linear amount of space.

Comment: While doing `sqrt decomposition` all the elements with a block are not necessary to  be include in a  subarray for a query , so how keep the count maximum element  in a block , since maximum element within a block changes based on the value of `D`

Comment: @DreamWorks The array is not split into blocks. Queries are (based on the value of their `D`).

Comment: Can you provide a  sudo code , it will be more clear